# Is std::chrono::seconds lightweight?

Tags: c++, c++11

For a embedded project I'd like to use `std::chrono::seconds` to represent timeout values, especially for the reason of typesaftyness. This requires `std::chrono::seconds` to be fast constructible from an unsigned int type and also passing by value has to be very fast. Is that the case?

Comment: As from the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration) it looks `std::chrono::seconds` does what you want.

Comment: If you want to construct from `unsigned int`, why not use `std::chrono::duration<unsigned int>` instead? `std::chrono::seconds` uses signed type and may use more bits than you actually need.

Comment: In practice, `seconds` will usually use a 64-bit representation - the standard specifies at least 35 bits. So a 32-bit representation (or perhaps even smaller, depending on your needs) might be faster, if the range is large enough for you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be asked to a profiler.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes I think profiling is unnecessary since std::chrono::duration is a wrapper class around an integer. That can't be slower than using the integer itself.

Comment: Of course it can be. Your question doesn't even define "fast" or what implementation you are using, so the question is completely unanswerable.

Comment: Fast means not significantly slower than using a raw integer. Implementation is libcxx

Comment: Define "significant". Also, you need to put that in the question.

Comment: The Question was not very precise that's right, but since user2079303 already told me everything I wanted to know, I don't want to spend much time on rephrasing it.

Comment: @TNA:  I have no idea what's up with all the hostility on this.  If it helps, here is a good writeup authored by the people who designed `chrono::seconds`:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2661.htm#duration

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Because it's unanswerable and a terrible question. The only meaningful answer to "Is std::chrono fast enough for me?" is "Profile it".

Comment: @TNA: If it turns out that the `chrono::duration` facility is too expensive for your code (possibly customized with `unsigned int` as user2079303's good answer correctly describes), then it will be likely that the use of the built-in integral types will also be too expensive for your code.  I.e. `chrono::duration` is a very thin wrapper around an arithmetic type.  It adds type safety, but not overhead (unless perhaps you turn off inlining).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update. It seems that I can be bothered to check the standard sometimes.

Here's what the standard says about copy construction of duration.

20.11.5.1
duration constructors

```
template <class Rep2, class Period2>
constexpr duration(const duration<Rep2, Period2>& d);
```

> Effects: Constructs an object of type `duration`, constructing `rep_` from

```
duration_cast<duration>(d).count()
```

20.11.5.7 duration_cast

```
template <class ToDuration, class Rep, class Period>
constexpr ToDuration duration_cast(const duration<Rep, Period>& d);
```

> 2 Returns: Let CF be

```
ratio_divide<Period, typename ToDuration::period>
```

> — If `CF::num == 1` and `CF::den == 1`, returns

```
ToDuration(static_cast<typename ToDuration::rep>(d.count()))
```

20.11.5.2 duration observer

> constexpr rep count() const; 1 Returns: rep_.

From all this, unless I'm mistaken, copy constructor should get the rep from original, static_casts it to new rep type (which is the same in this case) and constructs the new duration object with the rep constructor. At least, in effect. If the implementation does something incredibly heavy in addition to that, consider throwing it away.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find limitations to member data in the standard but the [document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2661.htm) linked by Howard Hinnant is probably more credible source than cppreference.com and it states:

> The representation stores a count of ticks. This count is the only
>   data member stored in a duration

As nice as this sounds, if the performance matters, profile your code. If it doesn't matter, this question is pointless.

Old answer...

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration)

> The only data stored in a duration is a tick count of type Rep.

So, yes, it seems to be fast for value passing. And as I suggested in the comment, `std::chrono::duration<unsigned int>` should be slightly more efficient and you shouldn't then need to worry about overflows as long as the original `unsigned int` doesn't overflow.

Comment: This is some kind of vague hope or opinion, rather than a fact.

Comment: If you want facts, you read through the standard to find out if cppreference.com is correct. If you want to be absolutely sure, you read the source code of your standard library. If you can't be bothered, you can ask it on stackoverflow :) Frankly, any implementation that does store more than the tick count is not very good, in my opinion.

Comment: That wording would not ban slow implementations, Standard or not. And "profile" is the only means to determine the result, regardless of what random stackoverflowers say or what you feel after reading the library source code.

Comment: What on earth would the copy constructor do besides copy the data? Of course, for all x, the answer for question "Is x fast enough?", is always "Profile x.". The quoted wording is plenty enough in my opinion to consider using `std::chrono::duration` as an option rather than start implementing your own. You can't profile it before you use it in your code (and micro benchmarks are not substitute for profiling).

Comment: `If you can't be bothered, you can ask it on stackoverflow` You meant "answer", not "ask", by the looks of it!

Comment: Touché. I usually won't bother unless the OP does. Helping out is one thing, doing others work for them is another.

Answer (score 5):

What follows is a possible partial implementation of `seconds` that can be slower than using integers directly.

```
template <typename T>
struct duration<T, ratio<1>> {
    using rep = T;
    using period = ratio<1>;

    duration(T r) : r(r) { this_thread::sleep_for(hours(1)); }

private:
    T r;
};
```

Comment: Yeah, try to ship this.

Comment: True, yet useless. Are you aware of any implementations of C++ that ship with anything analogous to the above? I'd even accept one you brewed yourself: a pathologically evil C++ compiler that does standards-conformant yet evil things.